# GWT - stockwatch example - event handling explanation

Tags: java, gwt

First of all, hi everyone. I'm new here and i just have started learning gwt. There is one thing that i dont understand regarding stockwatch example. First of all, there is add stock method, which adds new stock to a list. Inside that method we also add remove button and attach listener to it. My question is, how is it possible that indexOf attr is set, when u dont enter that part of code when u add new stock, u only enter that part when u click remove button. But this code works, and i cant find explanation why..I tried to debug app, but still having trouble to undestand. Sorry for my bad english.

```
private void addStock()
{
    final String symbol = newSymbolTextBox.getText().toUpperCase().trim();

    //validaciju vrsimo upotrebom regularnih izraza
    if(symbol.matches("[0-9A-Z]"))
    {
         Window.alert("'" + symbol + "' is not a valid symbol.");
         newSymbolTextBox.selectAll();
         return;

    }

    newSymbolTextBox.setText("");

    if(stocks.contains(symbol))
    {
        return;
    }

    int row = stocksFlexTable.getRowCount();
    stocks.add(symbol);
    stocksFlexTable.setText(row, 0, symbol);
    Button removeStockButton = new Button("x");

    removeStockButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            int indexOf = stocks.indexOf(symbol);
            stocks.remove(indexOf);
            stocksFlexTable.removeRow(indexOf + 1);

        }
    });

    stocksFlexTable.setWidget(row, 3, removeStockButton);

    refreshWatchList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how is it possible that indexOf attr is set, when u
>   dont enter that part of code when u add new stock, u only enter that
>   part when u click remove button.

Read about [anonymous inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html#innerClasses) as event listeners. **new ClickHandler()** provides a handler to each Button, which catches the click event, with the functionality that will remove the line, whenever the specific delete button is pressed. Every button has it's own clickHandler.

**indexOf** is not a great name for a variable. I would rather stick to **removedIndex**, used in the [www.gwtproject.org](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/design.html) sample code:

```
    // Add a button to remove this stock from the table.
    Button removeStockButton = new Button("x");
    removeStockButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            int removedIndex = stocks.indexOf(symbol);
            stocks.remove(removedIndex);
            stocksFlexTable.removeRow(removedIndex + 1);
        }
    });
    stocksFlexTable.setWidget(row, 3, removeStockButton);
```